# Use hardlink to have one file in multiple locations (different drives)

Tags: windows-10, git, symbolic-link

I'd like to have one file at different drives on Windows. I tried using hard link

```
mklink /H I:\file.bib C:\file.bib
```

But I get the following message.

```
The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive
```

Any suggestions on alternate ways?
I'm trying to do this to update the complete file content and not the symlink to git repository

Comment: Hard links only work within on drive. If you want to create a link that involves two drives you can only use symbolic links.

Comment: @Robert Many thanks for the response. I could use symbolic links. However, when the file is pushed to git repository only the path to the target file appears.

Comment: Then reverse it. Place the original file in the git directory and then create a symbolic link from it.